# ("Trying to get property 'id' of non-object") what is missing in my code when importing excel file in laravel with table relationship

Tags: excel, laravel

hi all please let me know the missing how to fix this one thanks too for all

here is the response when importing it said  ("Trying to get property 'id' of non-object") what is missing in my code  when  importing  excel file in laravel with table relationship

here is the response when importing it said  ("Trying to get property 'id' of non-object") what is missing in my code  when  importing  excel file in laravel with table relationship

here is my importing code

```
 <?php
        
        namespace App\Imports;
        use App\Entities\Partners\ProjectZones;
        use App\Entities\Projects\Project;
        use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
        use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
        use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
        use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;
        
        
        class ProjectImport implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow,WithValidation
        {
        
            private $zones;
        
            public function __construct()
            {
                $this->zones = ProjectZones::select('id','name')->get();
            }
            /**
            * @param array $row
            *
            * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
            */
           public function collection(Collection $rows)
            {
        
                foreach($rows as $row){
                    $zone = $this->zones->where('name',$row['zonename'])->first();
                    $data=[
        
                   'name'     => $row['name'],
                   'description'    => $row['description'],
                   'prolocation'    => $row['prolocation'], 
                   'projectcategory' => $row['projectcategory'],
                   'projecttag' => $row['projecttag'],
                   'code'     => $row['code'],
                   'proposal_date'    => $row['proposal_date'], 
                   'start_date' => $row['start_date'],
                   'end_date'     => $row['end_date'],
                   'due_date'    => $row['due_date'], 
                   'proposal_value'    => $row['proposal_value'], 
                   'contractor'    => $row['contractor'], 
                   'subcontractor' => $row['subcontractor'],
                   'SupplimentaryCost' => $row['supplimentarycost'],
                   'AdditionalWorkCost' => $row['additionalworkcost'],
                   'TotalProjectCost' => $row['totalprojectcost'],
                   'zone_id' => $zone->id
        
                ];
        
                Project::create($data);
            }
        
        }
              public function rules(): array
            {
                return[
                    'name'      => 'required|max:50',
                    'description' => 'required|max:50',
                    'prolocation' => 'required|max:50',
                    'projectcategory'    => 'required|max:255',
                    'projecttag'    => 'required|max:255',
                    'code'    => 'required:code|numeric|unique:projects,code',
                    'proposal_date'  => 'required|max:50',
                    'start_date'     => 'required|max:50',
                    'end_date'       => 'required|max:50',
                    'due_date'       => 'required|max:50',
                    'proposal_value' => 'required|numeric',
                    'contractor'    => 'nullable|max:255',
                    'subcontractor'    => 'nullable|max:255',
                    'SupplimentaryCost '    => 'nullable|max:255',
                    'AdditionalWorkCost  '    => 'nullable|max:255',
                    'TotalProjectCost   '    => 'nullable|max:255',
                ];
            }
        }
```

Comment: The error is being thrown at `'zone_id' => $zone->id`, your `$zone` variable is not an object. You need to do some debugging but basically your assignment of a value to `$zone` is failing.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an if else statement for the zone_id field in your data array like this

```
'zone_id' => $zone ? $zone->id : null
```

So this will check if the zone with that name exists and if it does it will take its id and save it to the array, but if zone_id is required for the array I recommend adding further validation if the zone exists before creating the data array.

Comment: o bro it works fine really thanks for everything bro you are too optimistic